# NaN resulting from sum of values in nodeJS

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, server, nan

I'm fairly new to Javascript. But I created an HTML code that takes input and then the NodeJS runs it on the server to calculate the sum. I downloaded both modules properly. But I still seem to get Nan as the sum of numbers.

The code seems to work properly for a friend. And I copy pasted his JS code to mine, still no luck.

**JS**

```
const express = require("express");

const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.get("/", function(req, res) {
      res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
});

app.post("/", function(req, res) {
      console.log(req.body);
      var num1, num2, total = 0;
      num1 = req.body.num1;
      num2 = req.body.num2;
      total = num1 + num2;
      console.log(total);
      res.send("The result of the calculation is " + total);
});

app.listen(3000, function() {
     console.log("The server is running on port 3000.");
});
```

**HTML**

```
<form action="/" method="POST">
    <input type="text " name="num1 " placeholder="First Number " />
    <input type="text " name="num2 " placeholder="Second Number " />
    <button type="submit " name="submit ">Calculate</button>
</form>
```

Comment: try `console.log(num1, num2, total);` to see what num1 and num2 are before you sum them

Comment: What does `console.log(req.body);` say? Note - `name="num1 "` why name attribute has trailing space?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove space from name, use type number and you can use parseInt too

```
`<form action="/" method="POST">
    <input type="number" name="num1" placeholder="First Number " />
    <input type="number" name="num2" placeholder="Second Number " />
    <button type="submit " name="submit ">Calculate</button>
</form>

const express = require("express");

const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.get("/", function(req, res) {
      res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
});

app.post("/", function(req, res) {

      var num1, num2, total = 0;
      consol.log(req.body.num2)
      num1 = parseInt(req.body.num1);a
      num2 = parseInt(req.body.num2);
      total = num1 + num2;
      res.send("The result of the calculation is " + total);
});

app.listen(3000, function() {
     console.log("The server is running on port 3000.");
});`
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the trailing space in the `name` attribute, also if you're passing numbers why don't you set the `type` as `number`

And either one of the values or maybe both is getting passed as `undefined` hence you get `NaN`

Answer (score 0):

2 mistakes:

- you put spaces in the names
- you use text instead of numbers

Here is a correct code:

```
<form action="http://localhost:3000/" method="POST">
    <input type="number" name="num1" placeholder="First Number" />
    <input type="number" name="num2" placeholder="Second Number" />
    <button type="submit" name="submit">Calculate</button>
</form>


const express = require("express");

const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.get("/", function(req, res) {
      res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
});

app.post("/", function(req, res) {
      console.log(req.body);
      var num1, num2, total = 0;
      num1 = +req.body.num1;
      num2 = +req.body.num2;
      total = num1 + num2;
      console.log(total);
      res.send("The result of the calculation is " + total);
});

app.listen(3000, function() {
     console.log("The server is running on port 3000.");
});
```